# Linq не правильно работает запрос

Tags: c#, linq

Всем доброго времени суток.

У меня проблема с вводом данных из таблицы

при SQL запросе:

```
SELECT 
    item_name 
    ,item_count
    ,item_total
    ,DATE
FROM [pos].[dbo].[POS_LOG_DETAIL]
WHERE 
    DATE >= '01-10-2015 0:0:00' AND 
    DATE < '01-10-2015 23:59:59' 
    -- and pos_id in(3,4)
    AND item_name = 'Кофе'
    AND item_total IS NOT NULL
```

я получаю следующий результат выборки

```
Кофе    1   100 2015-10-01 18:13:50.000
Кофе    1   100 2015-10-01 18:16:55.000
Кофе    2   200 2015-10-01 18:22:50.000
Кофе    1   100 2015-10-01 18:24:19.000
Кофе    2   200 2015-10-01 18:31:34.000
Кофе    2   200 2015-10-01 18:46:21.000
Кофе    2   200 2015-10-01 18:56:33.000
Кофе    1   100 2015-10-01 19:03:25.000
```

А при запросе из контроллера получаю следующие данные

```
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:22:50
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:22:50
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:22:50
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:22:50
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:22:50
Кофе    1   100 01.10.2015 18:24:19
Кофе    1   100 01.10.2015 18:24:19
Кофе    1   100 01.10.2015 18:24:19
Кофе    1   100 01.10.2015 18:24:19
Кофе    1   100 01.10.2015 18:24:19
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:46:21
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:46:21
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:46:21
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:46:21
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:56:33
Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:56:33
Кофе    1   100 01.10.2015 19:03:25
Кофе    1   100 01.10.2015 19:03:25
Кофе    1   100 01.10.2015 19:03:25
```

Класс

```
public class Pos_Log_Detail
    {
        public string pos_id { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int id_string { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public int fraction { get; set; }
        public string item_code { get; set; }
        public string item_name { get; set; }
        public Double ? item_count { get; set; }
        public Double ? item_price { get; set; }
        public Double ? item_total { get; set; }
        public Double ? item_discount { get; set; }
        public string item_barcode { get; set; }
        public int offset { get; set; }
        public int FunctionNumber { get; set; }
        public string check_number { get; set; }
        public string second_check_number { get; set; }
        public string item_discount_type { get; set; }
        public string card_number { get; set; }
        public string FuelingPointNo { get; set; }

    }
```

Контроллер

```
 public class PosLogDetailController : Controller
    {
        private IPosLogDetail repository;
        public PosLogDetailController(IPosLogDetail repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public ViewResult List()
        {



            var res = repository.PosLogDetail
                .Where(b => b.date >= new DateTime(2015,10,1,00,00,00) && b.date < new DateTime(2015,10,1,23,59,59) && b.item_total.HasValue && b.item_name == "Кофе")
                .OrderBy(b=>b.date)
                .ToList();
            return View(res.ToList());

        }
    }
```

View

```
@foreach (var p in @Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@p.id</td>
                <td>@p.item_name</td>
                <td>@p.item_count</td>
                <td>@p.item_total</td>
                <td>@p.date</td>

            </tr>
        }
```

Отладчик

```
+       repository.PosLogDetail {SELECT 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[pos_id] AS [pos_id], 
    [Extent1].[id_string] AS [id_string], 
    [Extent1].[date] AS [date], 
    [Extent1].[fraction] AS [fraction], 
    [Extent1].[item_code] AS [item_code], 
    [Extent1].[item_name] AS [item_name], 
    [Extent1].[item_count] AS [item_count], 
    [Extent1].[item_price] AS [item_price], 
    [Extent1].[item_total] AS [item_total], 
    [Extent1].[item_discount] AS [item_discount], 
    [Extent1].[item_barcode] AS [item_barcode], 
    [Extent1].[offset] AS [offset], 
    [Extent1].[FunctionNumber] AS [FunctionNumber], 
    [Extent1].[check_number] AS [check_number], 
    [Extent1].[second_check_number] AS [second_check_number], 
    [Extent1].[item_discount_type] AS [item_discount_type], 
    [Extent1].[card_number] AS [card_number], 
    [Extent1].[FuelingPointNo] AS [FuelingPointNo]
    FROM [dbo].[Pos_Log_Detail] AS [Extent1]}   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail> {System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail>}
-       res Count = 19  System.Collections.Generic.List<Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail>
-       [0] {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
        card_number null    string
        check_number    null    string
+       date    {01.10.2015 18:22:50}   System.DateTime
        fraction    11  int
        FuelingPointNo  null    string
        FunctionNumber  2   int
        id  1111    int
        id_string   1   int
        item_barcode    null    string
        item_code   "289"   string
        item_count  2.0 double?
        item_discount   null    double?
        item_discount_type  null    string
        item_name   "Кофе"  string
        item_price  null    double?
        item_total  200.0   double?
        offset  0   int
        pos_id  "5" string
        second_check_number null    string
-       [1] {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
        card_number null    string
        check_number    null    string
+       date    {01.10.2015 18:22:50}   System.DateTime
        fraction    11  int
        FuelingPointNo  null    string
        FunctionNumber  2   int
        id  1111    int
        id_string   1   int
        item_barcode    null    string
        item_code   "289"   string
        item_count  2.0 double?
        item_discount   null    double?
        item_discount_type  null    string
        item_name   "Кофе"  string
        item_price  null    double?
        item_total  200.0   double?
        offset  0   int
        pos_id  "5" string
        second_check_number null    string
+       [2] {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [3] {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [4] {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [5] {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [6] {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [7] {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [8] {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [9] {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [10]    {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [11]    {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [12]    {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [13]    {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [14]    {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [15]    {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [16]    {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [17]    {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
+       [18]    {Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail}  Sibur.Domain.Entities.Pos_Log_Detail
-       Raw View        
        Capacity    32  int
        Count   19  int
+       Static members      
+       Non-Public members      
+       this    {Sibur.WebUI.Controllers.PosLogDetailController}    Sibur.WebUI.Controllers.PosLogDetailController
```

Во первых у меня не выводятся некоторые строки, а второе выводятся одни и те же по несколько раз.
Подскажите где у меня ошибка и как ее исправить.

Comment: А почему `&`, а не `&&`?

Comment: И ещё, в таблице реально сколько записей, отвечающих данным `Кофе    2   200 01.10.2015 18:22:50`? Может, вы модифицирует таблицу в другом месте в коде?

Comment: Запись всего одна, таблицу я не модифицирую, мне нужно только достать из нее данные и вывести пользователю

Comment: Если я создаю абстрактное хранилище, то запрос работает правильно

Comment: Если запись всего одна, то такой результат (с несколькими записями) быть не может. У вас наверное непорядок во View? Гляньте, что у вас реально оказывается в `res` в отладчике.

Comment: а зачем дважды приводить один набор к List?

Comment: Dmitry, я убрал .ToList() результат от этого не поменялся

Comment: VladD, в `res` попадает тоже самое что и выводит View.

Comment: @tlk вы точно выбираете из одной и той же базы? Запустите SQL Server Profiler и посмотрите на реально выполняемый запрос.

Comment: @PashaPash [ссылка](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/D52r/iuTxYx8ES) вот что показывает SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: @tlk значит проблема в вашей реализации `repository.PosLogDetail`. она вычитывает в память все (???) записи из базы и (скорее всего) что-то с ними делает (возможно, join на что-то еще). покажите код.

Comment: @tlk но вообще такой "репозиторий" даст вам ужасную проблему с производительностью (вне зависимости от того, почините вы его или нет). избавляйтесь от него.

Comment: @PashaPash  `public interface IPosLogDetail
    {
        IEnumerable<Pos_Log_Detail> PosLogDetail { get; }
    }` надеюсь что это то что вы хотели увидеть

Comment: поменяй `IEnumerable` на `IQueryable`. Ну и в запросе добавь `Select` конкретно 4 полей - сейчас, так как ничего не указано, тянутся все поля

Comment: @tlk нет, я хотел увидеть **реализацию** интерфейса

Comment: @PashaPash `public class EFPosLogDetail:IPosLogDetail
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
        public IEnumerable<Pos_Log_Detail> PosLogDetail
        {
            get { return context.PosLogDetail; }
        }
    }`

Comment: @tlk меняйте на IQueryable (как выше Grundy) предложил. и проверяйте, что тянете данные из той же базы (хотя бы количество строк сравните)

Comment: @Grundy, Огромное вам Спасибо! Сделал как вы сказали теперь выборка корректна. `838 Кофе 1 100 01.10.2015 18:13:50
839 Кофе 1 100 01.10.2015 18:16:55
1111 Кофе 2 200 01.10.2015 18:22:50
1112 Кофе 1 100 01.10.2015 18:24:19
841 Кофе 2 200 01.10.2015 18:31:34
1127 Кофе 2 200 01.10.2015 18:46:21
848 Кофе 2 200 01.10.2015 18:56:33
851 Кофе 1 100 01.10.2015 19:03:25`

Comment: @PashaPash, Вам также огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае проблема в `IPosLogDetail` и конкретно в свойстве

```
IEnumerable<Pos_Log_Detail> PosLogDetail
```

Здесь нужно использовать `IQueryable<Pos_Log_Detail> PosLogDetail`, так как это позволит сначала сформировать конкретный запрос и только потом выполнить его вызвав `ToList` или подобную функцию.

а так же в текущем запросе не указываются конкретные поля, поэтому из базы вытягиваются все столбцы какие есть.
Для решения можно использовать `Select` в котором указать только нужные поля, например так:

```
var res = repository.PosLogDetail
            .Where(b => b.date >= new DateTime(2015,10,1,00,00,00) && b.date < new DateTime(2015,10,1,23,59,59) && b.item_total.HasValue && b.item_name == "Кофе")
            .OrderBy(b=>b.date)
            .Select(b=> new {
                b.item_name,
                b.item_count,
                b.item_total,
                b.date
             })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: помогла замена `IEnumerable`на`IQueryable`

Comment: @tlk, попытался немного пояснить почему :-)